# JS object returned but responseText doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am posting a call to a method that just returns a string and my post request returns an object with a string in the responseText field, but the `d.responseText` returns "undefined."
Anyone know why? I thought it was because it was AJAX but why is does the var d have the correct value?

```
var d = $.post("/home/status_update", function(data) {return data});
console.log(d);
console.log(d.responseText);
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's one of the far most common errors I'm finding here on AJAX requests: many people don't realize that AJAX is *A*synchronous, you can't expect that your `d` variable gets valued because *the code continues its execution* regardless of the completion of the AJAX request.

You can use the retrieved value **only** when the request-response roundtrip has been completed.

What you have to do is to actually *use* the returned value *inside* the `function(data)`, because you are guaranteed that it will be executed only *after* the value is actually retrieved.

The other user obtains the same thing by binding the `done` event, that is fired upon the completion of the AJAX request/response. It's the same thing coded in a slight different manner.
The shorthand is:

```
var d = $.post("/home/status_update", function(data) {console.log(data);});
```

---

Bear in mind that, as a general application architecture, with AJAX requests you cannot expect to use a single function, you will define functions that will manupulate your response upon every AJAX completion.
Try to think your application in a more "fragmented" way.

Answer (score 5):

`$.post` returns a promise object, try using it.

```
var d = $.post("/home/status_update");
d.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```